# Select element inside next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select each `$('div span:eq(0)').text()` inside `$('div#first')`. How can I string these two selectors together?

```
<div id="first">Some stuff to be ignored.</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Some text</span> <!-- need this -->
        <span>Skipped text</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Some text</span>  <!-- and this -->
        <span>Skipped text</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- this pattern continues unknown # of times -->
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In your HTML snippet above, div#first is empty...will the rest of the HTML actually be contained within div#first?

Comment: Unfortunately he expressed his wishes wrongly, I think he wants to get the text in the spans and put it int the `#first` element because `#first` doesn't contain anything besides the `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Edited example to be more clear. Im simply capturing the text in the span to be used for something else.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit didn't really help to clarify your question... One important note: NEVER! use an id-selector like this: `$('div#first')` always write this: `$('#first')` instead!

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, didnt realize I was doing that wrong. What about for classes? `$(div.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `li` instead of `div`.

```
// Using #first.next()-v as #first just has a &nbsp;
$('li', $('#first').next()).find('span:eq(0)').text('Updated text');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rFUB8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div span:eq(0)', 'div#first').text()
```

Or if you want to handle them one at a time:

```
$('div span:eq(0)', 'div#first').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

If you're talking about putting those spans in 'div#first', you can use:

```
$('div#first').append($('div span:eq(0)'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately he expressed his wishes wrongly, I think he wants to get the text in the spans and put it int the `#first` element because `#first` doesn't contain anything besides the `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Well if there's nothing in the `#first` div how can you test?

Comment: I don't think he meant to leave it like that? Surely he saw the comments on his question.

Comment: Actually, I think this is just example code, not the real code.